# How to forbid my PC in LAN to make DNS queries? (in a PC -> VPN gateway scenario)

Tags: iptables, dns, vpn, gateway, bind9

scenario: i have 2 pc's that are connected to each other over ethernet in a lan and one of the pc's is configured as a gateway that tunnels the traffic of the other pc over to a vpn service. everything seems to work. the traffic is tunneled through the vpn service and i also dont have dns leaks while the gateway is connected to the vpn. but if i disconnect the vpn then the other pc on my local network can somehow still make dns queries even though no other connection to the internet can be made from it.

how can i avoid this from happening? dns queries should only be allowed if the vpn connection is established. edit: (and only through the vpn's dns server. I believe the dns request is made through my isp's dns servers as soon as i disconnect the vpn even though i configured the bind9 server on the gateway. i could be wrong though.)

what i did on the gateway is the following:
i set up ipv4 forwarding and some iptables rules

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o tun0 -j MASQUERADE
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o tun0 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i tun0 -o eth0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

and i also installed a bind9 server and configured it to forward the dns queries to the vpns dns (because i had dns leaks)

my guess is that i have to drop all the network traffic that doesnt follow the rules above

e.g. with

```
sudo iptables -P FORWARD DROP
sudo iptables -P INPUT DROP
```

but that breaks my connection completely. any ideas?

Comment: DNS uses TCP port 53, so `DROP` any incoming packets from the host on that TCP port?

Comment: Ok, thank you. I will try that. I guess I can not even make DNS queries through the VPN then anymore? But let's see

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drop all DNS queries that don't go to the VPN. DNS can use UDP port 53 or TCP port 53.

```
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 ! -o tun0 -p udp --dport 53 -j DROP
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 ! -o tun0 -p tcp --dport 53 -j DROP
```

All packets that come from `eth0` and want to leave via an interface other than `tun0` and have the destination port 53 will be dropped.

You may want to log the packets before dropping to analyze them.

You may want to use `REJECT` instead of `DROP` so the client knows not to wait for an answer.

You may want to drop or reject all packets, not just port 53, to prevent any traffic.

Comment: Thank you for you help. I followed your advice but the client pc is still able to resolve domains over the network.

Comment: I watched the network traffic and the DNS queries go over the wifi adapter of the gateway (which is connected to the internet and vpn) but not the tun0 adapter. I am even more confused now... if I drop all other packets then only connections over openvpn are established (which would be what i want) but the client pc is then not able to resolve any domains over the network somehow

Comment: What is the ip address of the DNS server the client pc uses? Is it an address that is reachable through the VPN?